# How to get data attribute from dynamic button if it changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to obtain the value of an attribute (here the title) of a dynamic button (created by the multiselect library) and display it in a text box, if there is a change.

Here's what I have now:

```js
// for combine checkbox value

$(function() {
  $('input').on('click', function() {
    var values = [];
    $('input[name=test]:checked').each(function() {
      values.push($(this).parent().text());
    });
    $('[name="result"]').attr({
      value: values.join('|')
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form oninput="txtrequete.value = ( 
      txtdomain.value +  ';' +  result.value).replace(/\s+/g, '');" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
  FINAL
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txtrequete" disabled="disabled" size='70'>
  </div>
  TEXT TEST FOR CONCAT
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txtdomain" id="domainId" value="testvalue" />
  </div>
  CHECKBOX TEST FOR CONCAT
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" /> test3</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" /> test4</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="result" disabled="disabled" />
  </div>

  <div>
    BUTTON CREATED FROM MULTISELECT JQUERY LIBRARY
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="India, United State, Canada, Taiwan" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="multiselect-selected-text">4 selected</span> <b class="caret"></b></button>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="spantitle" disabled="disabled" value="i would like the title value 'India, United State, Canada, Taiwan' HERE from the button attribute if change" size="70" />
  </div>
</form>
```

has anyone ever used this before?  Thank you in advance

```
<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown"
    title="India, United State, Canada, Taiwan" aria-expanded="true">

    <span class="multiselect-selected-text">4 selected</span>
    <b class="caret"></b></button>div>
<input type="text" name="spantitle" disabled="disabled"
    value="i would like the title value 'India, United State, Canada, Taiwan' HERE from the button attribute if change"
    size="70" />
</div>
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking yet.  If an existing button element just has its title changed dynamically you. might have to look into a mutation observer ?  Otherwise, if a new element or markup is created, why not just get the title attribute with jQuery in a call back and put it into your input, span, or whatever you are using to display that.  Seems like maybe you could use a tooltip or something like that also ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an event listener, just simply use the title attribute of your button and set it as value of your input field, like:

```
$('input[name=spantitle]').val($('.multiselect ').attr('title'));
```

If you are not sure when or how the dynamic changes happen, you could use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

> The MutationObserver interface provides the ability to watch for
>   changes being made to the DOM tree. It is designed as a replacement
>   for the older Mutation Events feature which was part of the DOM3
>   Events specification.

Here is an example how it could work:

```js
// for combine checkbox value

$(function() {
  $('input').on('click', function() {
    var values = [];
    $('input[name=test]:checked').each(function() {
      values.push($(this).parent().text());
    });
    $('[name="result"]').attr({
      value: values.join('|')
    });
  });
});


$('#test').on('click', () => {
  $('.multiselect ').attr('title', 'Just another attribute');
});

var observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
      $('input[name=spantitle]').val($('.multiselect ').attr('title'));
    }
  });
});

observer.observe($('.multiselect')[0], {
  attributes: true // Listening to the attribute changes
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form oninput="txtrequete.value = ( 
      txtdomain.value +  ';' +  result.value).replace(/\s+/g, '');" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
  FINAL
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txtrequete" disabled="disabled" size='70'>
  </div>
  TEXT TEST FOR CONCAT
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="txtdomain" id="domainId" value="testvalue" />
  </div>
  CHECKBOX TEST FOR CONCAT
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" /> test3</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test" /> test4</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="result" disabled="disabled" />
  </div>

  <div>
    BUTTON CREATED FROM MULTISELECT JQUERY LIBRARY
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="India, United State, Canada, Taiwan" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="multiselect-selected-text">4 selected</span> <b class="caret"></b></button>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="spantitle" disabled="disabled" value="i would like the title value 'India, United State, Canada, Taiwan' HERE from the button attribute if change" size="70" />
  </div>
</form>

<button id="test">Test me!</button>
```

Click on the button "Test me!" to change the title attribute and you may see that the object `observer` will change the value of your input field.